# Find the dimension of the vector space of solutions of $3 \times 4$ matrices $N$ where $N^{T}M=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let $M$ be the $3 \times 4$ matrix displayed below
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 &3&2&4\\
2&4&3&5\\
3&5&4&6\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I want to find the dimension of the vector space of solutions of $3 \times 4$ matrices $N$ where $N^{T}M=0$ but I am having some trouble.

*Thoughts on the matter:*

**I am in general, wondering if there is some sort of conceptional insight** towards doing this problem, but here is what I've thought.

To say that we have a matrix $N$ where $N^{T}M=0$ is the same as saying that $M^{T}N=0$. Displayed below as 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 &2&3\\
3&4&5\\
2&3&4 \\
4&5&6 \\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
n_{11} &n_{12}&n_{13}&n_{14}\\
n_{21}&n_{22}&n_{23}&n_{24}\\
n_{31}&n_{32}&n_{33}&n_{34}\\
\end{bmatrix}=0$$
I can think of this as four seperate systems of equations of the form 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 &2&3\\
3&4&5\\
2&3&4 \\
4&5&6 \\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
n_{1j} \\
n_{2j}\\
n_{3j}\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
for $j=1,2,3,4$.  I found the rank of the matrix $M^{T}$ to be $2$ using column reduction which should imply that the null space of linear map $\mathbb{C}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{4}$ to have dimesion $3-2=1$. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

row reducing $ M^\top =\pmatrix{
1 &2&3\\
3&4&5\\
2&3&4 \\
4&5&6 },\, $ i get $\pmatrix{1&0&-1\\0&1&2\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}.$

therefore the null space of $M^\top$ is spanned $(1, -2, 1)^\top.$  we have $N^\top M = 0 \iff M^\top N = 0.$ that is every column of $N$ is a multiple of $(1, -2, 1)^\top.$

Comment: How do I conclude that the null space is spanned by $(1,-2,1)^{T}$?

Comment: @user135520, that is the only nonzero solution of $M^\top x = 0$ up to a scalar multiple. that is what our row reduced system told us.

Comment: So in the last line do you mean that every column of N is a multiple of that non-zero solution?

Comment: @user135520, including the trivial zero multiple.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that each column of your solution matrix is independent of each other,  so you may just find the direction of the Null space for M and just copy that general solution in each of the columns. You could combine then independently of each other, so I'm guessing you'd get 1*4 degrees of freedom for your space of solution matrices

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on from your working: $M^T$ has rank $2$ and nullity $1$.  So for each $j$, the quantities $n_{1j},n_{2j},n_{3j}$ will be given in terms of one parameter.  So the solutions for the whole of $N$ will involve $4$ parameters, and the solution space has dimension $4$.  Specifically, a basis for the space will consist of
$$\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\cr-2&0&0&0\cr1&0&0&0\cr}\,,\ 
  \pmatrix{0&1&0&0\cr0&-2&0&0\cr0&1&0&0\cr}\,,\ 
  \pmatrix{0&0&1&0\cr0&0&-2&0\cr0&0&1&0\cr}\,,\ 
  \pmatrix{0&0&0&1\cr0&0&0&-2\cr0&0&0&1\cr}\,.$$

Comment: Thanks this answer along with abel's answered made the solution clear.